# Slides using single javascript declaration call a file.js from Multiple file.js and .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to creat Slides with HTML and CSS load form multi file.js and file.css

For example, I have a handful of numbered .JS and CSS files, and place them within your slides and styles directory, like so:
[image: Struction directory]
Slides function can be clicked Play each slide, users can press next and previous to view each slide simple

> An example image of my slides

[image: An example image of my slides]

> Example HTML

```html
 <div class="wrap">
   <div id="slides">
      <!-- load in slides form a file.js -->
   </div>
 </div>
```

> Example JS

```js
loadContent : function() {
      Slides.container.hide();
      for ( var i = 0; i < Slides.totalSlides; i++ ) {
         $('<div id="#slide-' + i + '"></div>')
            .load('.slides/' + i + '.js')
            .appendTo(Slides.container);
         }
      Slides.container.show();
   },
```

Slide controls to button Next and Previous 
My example:

```js
var each;
     
          if ( !totalSlides ) throw new Error('Please pass the total number of slides.');
          Slides.totalSlides = totalSlides;
     
      Slides.loadContent('slides/slide'+Slides.Slideindex+'.js');
      
       var nextbutton = document.getElementById('next');
       var prebutton = document.getElementById('pre');
       nextbutton.addEventListener('click',function(){
        Slides.Slideindex++;
       Slides.loadContent('slides/slide'+Slides.Slideindex+'.js');
       })
       prebutton.addEventListener('click',function(){
        Slides.Slideindex--;
       Slides.loadContent('slides/slide'+Slides.Slideindex+'.js');
       })
          each = Slides.container.children('div');
           
          // Determine the width of our canvas
          Slides.slideWidth = each.width() + ( parseInt( each.css('margin-right'), 10 ) );
     
          Slides.keyPress();
       },
```

All right; let's do this.

```js
Slides.init(160); //call 160 file.js
```

Comment: What doesn’t work here?

Comment: I do not know how to load each file.js and a file.css into a slide on the index page

Comment: Is there already a separate HTML file for each slide as well? If so, you could just statically link the scripts & styles to each file as you would normally (using `<script>` and `<link>`) then use an `<iframe>` to render the current slide.

Comment: Currently I don't want to use <iframe>, I want to call elements from file.js load on <div> slide </div>

Comment: Please remove all snippets, include code only or create demo in one snippet, currently your each snippet is broken.